# Coordinate calculation $(x,y)$ in $2$ dimensions based on given data

Tags: coordinate-systems

I would like your help in the following problem:

Given that I have two cartesian coordinates: $S$ for the source at $(2.3,7.1)$ and T for the target at $(3,6)$. While a vehicle is moving from source to target at a constant speed of $0.1$ m/s, what are the cartesian coordinates of the vehicle $5$ seconds after the movement started?

Thank you and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Find the equation of the line through $S$ and $T$.  You have two points, so the [two-point form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) is what you want.  How far does the vehicle move?  You want the point on the line that is that far from $S$.  Write the equation for a circle around S with radius the distance the vehicle moves.  Solve that simultaneously with the equation for the line.